# How can I select the minimum sub-sequence using LINQ?

Tags: linq

If I have an array of golf results:

```
 -3, +5, -3, 0, +1, +8, 0, +6, +2, -8, +5
```

I need to find a sequence of three adjacent numbers which have the minimum sum. For this example, the sub-sequences would be:

```
 [-3, +5, -3]
 [+5, -3,  0]
 [-3,  0, +1]
 ... etc ...
 [+2, -8, +5]
```

And the minimum sequence would be `[-3, 0, +1]` having a sum of -2.

Comment: Do I need some golf knowledge to understand it ? Because I am not really sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry - By top results I mean the lowest scores (the more negative number- the better). By coherent I mean the results that are linked together (next to each other)

Comment: Where comes the top 3 into play? Your desired result contains all. Apart from that it contains two `-3`. Why is that?

Comment: But how they are linked? How provided result is desired while you want 3 results? Seems there is only one change in your result (from -2 to -3), magic? Put some real effort to explain your problem, people won't keep wasting time here asking you for clarifications...

Comment: Sorry again - I've updated my question. I tried to highlight the top 3 by making them bold, but it only resulted in asterisks. The reason for including the whole result string was that the order is what makes them top 3. Let me know if I can clarify even more?

Comment: @user3515324 I posted a suggested edit which should hopefully make the question more clear for people.

Comment: Thank you Anthony - that definetly makes it more clear!!

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be done in LINQ?

Comment: I was just to publish an answer but the question was closed..

Comment: Its nice to see how a simple rewording of the question for clarity can bring a positive effect on an otherwise good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this LINQ query:

```
int[] golfResult = { -3, +5, -3, 0, +1, +8, 0, +6, +2, -8, +5 };
var combinations = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, golfResult.Length - 2)
                   select new { 
                       i1 = golfResult[i], 
                       i2 = golfResult[i + 1], 
                       i3 = golfResult[i + 2], 
                   };
var min = combinations.OrderBy(x => x.i1 + x.i2 + x.i3).First();
int[] minGolfResult = { min.i1, min.i2, min.i3 }; // -3, 0, +1
```

Of course you need to check if there are at least three results in the array.

Comment: That last line is a bit of C# syntax I've never come across before :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would do this with LINQ. I think a straight up iterative solution is easier to understand:

```
int[] scores = new[] { -3, 5, -3, 0, 1, 8, 0, 6, 2, -8, 5 };

int minimumSubsequence = int.MaxValue;
int minimumSubsequenceIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length - 2; i++)
{
    int sum = scores[i] + scores[i + 1] + scores[i + 2];

    if (sum < minimumSubsequence)
    {
        minimumSubsequence = sum;
        minimumSubsequenceIndex = i;
    }
}

// minimumSubsequenceIndex is index of the first item in the minimum subsequence
// minimumSubsequence is the minimum subsequence's sum.
```

Comment: I got caught up with something else, but this is the exact solution I was going to suggest, though wrapped in a function with a parameter for the sub-sequence length and returning just the sub-sequence index.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in LINQ, you can go this way:

```
int length = 3;
var scores = new List<int>() { -3, +5, -3, 0, +1, +8, 0, +6, +2, -8, +5 };
var results =
    scores
    .Select((value, index) => new
    {
        Value = scores.Skip(index - length + 1).Take(length).Sum(),
        Index = index - length + 1
    })
    .Skip(length - 1)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
    .First()
    .Index;
```

This creates a second list that sums all **length** preceeding elements and then sorts it. You have